# curl syntax not working. Rest API testing

Tags: unix, ubuntu, curl, wget

**Setup:**
I use the following link to test my REST api in Postman and it works fine:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/API/v1/RefreshTableCache?tables=UniqueLineNumbers,SpoolInfo&jobnumber=1234
```

**Problem:**
But trying to run it form unix command line it fails.

```
wget -S -q -O - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/API/v1/RefreshTableCache?tables=UniqueLineNumbers,SpoolInfo&jobnumber=1234
```

Looking at the API output, it is never receiving the jobnumber parameter.

**Question:**

What is the proper syntax to make wget or even curl pass the parameter??

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes around the entire url?

Comment: @peeskillet That was it... I had tried it already.. but I think I was trying a second thing at the same time too.  Feel free to post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` has a special meaning in the terminal. So when it is used in the URL, it is treated as that special character. To get around that, just wrap the URL in quotes

```
curl 'http://<...>/path?param1=value1&param2=value2'
```